# Why does $_POST convert string to boolean

Tags: php, string, forms, post, boolean

I have a very strange problem and I would like a second pair of eyes. I'm trying something that's supposed to be a very basic function. Sending a form with POST and retrieving the values.

```
<form action="index.php?a=2" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="'. $_GET["c"] .'">
                    <table id="_person_table">
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> FIRST NAME: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="afn" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[0].'"> </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> LAST NAME: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate">  <input type="text" name="overwrite_lastname" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[1].'"> </td>

                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> PHONE NUMBER: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="overwrite_phone_number" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[2].'"> </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> E MAIL: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="aem" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[3].'"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> STREET ADRESS: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="asa" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[4].'"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> FULL HOUSE NUMBER: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="ahn" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[5].'"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> POSTAL CODE:</td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="apc" id="_person_create_input" value="'.$record[6].'"> </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                    <center> <input type="image" src="img/alterUser.png" name="submit" alt="Submit" style="width:100px;height:100px; padding-top:1%;"> </center>
                </form>
```

Above is the form, when I var_dump each value separate it gives the string representation. However, ones its send and retrieved on index.php?a=2 it gives the following dump:

> ```
> array(10) { 
>    ["pk"]=> string(8) "10000007"
>    ["afn"]=> string(5) "Lisa" 
>    ["overwrite_lastname"]=> bool(true) 
>    ["overwrite_phone_number"]=> bool(true)
>    ["aem"]=> string(26) "lisa@example.com" 
>    ["asa"]=> string(19) "not applicable" 
>    ["ahn"]=> string(1) "0" 
>    ["apc"]=> string(6)
> ```

Why are 8 out of the 10 values in POST as expected but are `$_POST["overwrite_lastname"]` and `$_POST["overwrite_phone_number"]` converted to boolean values? I don't see it.

UPDATE #1: var_dump($record);

> array(8) {  [0]=> string(4) "Lisa"  [1]=> string(8) "Dijkstra"  [2]=>
>   string(10) "0643482515"  [3]=> string(17) "lisa@example.com"
>   [4]=> string(19) "not applicable"  [5]=> string(1) "0"  [6]=>
>   string(6) "9743LD"  [7]=> string(19) "TO BE IMPLEMENTED " }

UPDATE #2: After a good night of sleep I've found the cause.
I was checking if POST values were set with:

> if($_POST["afn"] != null && $_POST["overwrite_lastname"] =! null &&
>   $_POST["overwrite_phone_number"] =! null && $_POST["aem"] != null &&
>   $_POST["asa"] != null && $_POST["ahn"] !=null && $_POST["apc"]!= null)

as can be seen I switched != to =! for the values that returned as booleans. At least I learned that ! can be used to reference true.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($record)` and add that to the post?

Answer (score 0):

You Were using PHP wrong way , Try this

```
<form action="index.php?a=2" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="<?php echo $_GET["c"]; ?>">
                    <table id="_person_table">
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> FIRST NAME: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="afn" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $_GET["c"]; ?>"> </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> LAST NAME: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate">  <input type="text" name="overwrite_lastname" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $record[0]; ?>"> </td>

                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> PHONE NUMBER: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="overwrite_phone_number" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $record[1]; ?>"> </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> E MAIL: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="aem" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $record[2]; ?>"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> STREET ADRESS: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="asa" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $record[3]; ?>"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> FULL HOUSE NUMBER: </td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="ahn" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $record[4]; ?>"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "_person_create_table"> POSTAL CODE:</td>
                    <td id = "_table_nr_plate"> <input type="text" name="apc" id="_person_create_input" value="<?php echo $record[5]; ?>"> </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                    <center> <input type="image" src="img/alterUser.png" name="submit" alt="Submit" style="width:100px;height:100px; padding-top:1%;"> </center>
                </form>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that they didn't actually post the whole file,  and that form is actually in a string like `$form = '<form action="index.php?a=2" method="post">...'`

Comment: @samlev .. hmmm , may be you are right , I wish the user who asked the question could var_dump the script , and paste the error

Comment: Its part of an echo string where '. .' indicates: stop.append.$record[n].append.continue

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE #2: After a good night of sleep I've found the cause. I was checking if POST values were set with:

> if($_POST["afn"] != null && $_POST["overwrite_lastname"] =! null &&
>   $_POST["overwrite_phone_number"] =! null && $_POST["aem"] != null &&
>   $_POST["asa"] != null && $_POST["ahn"] !=null && $_POST["apc"]!= null)
>   as can be seen I switched != to =! for the values that returned as
>   booleans. At least I learned that ! can be used to reference true.